# Angular 9 display data from nested json, fetched from rest api

Tags: angular, typescript, rest, rxjs

I would like to know how to display certain properties from nested json data fetched from REST API.

It only shows as [Object object][Object object]. However I want to access and display properties stored within Entry -> Resource.

I cannot really figure out what the problem is... amongst component and the interface.. and even if I write extensionally on my html such as `{{observation.entry.resource}}`, it is not working....

Thank you very much in advance!

1. my service code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observation } from '../../models/observation';
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/table';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CovidService {

  private covidApi:string = "http://hapi.fhir.org/baseR4/Observation?code=94531-1";
  
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getData():Observable<Observation[]>{  
    return this.httpClient.get<Observation[]>(this.covidApi);
    
  }
}
```

2. my component code

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { CovidService } from '../../services/covid/covid.service';
import { Observation } from '../../models/observation';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';

import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';




@Component({
  selector: 'app-covid-status',
  templateUrl: './covid-status.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./covid-status.component.css']
})


export class CovidStatusComponent implements OnInit { 
   observations: Observation[];
   displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'entry','meta','status','subject'];
  
  constructor(private covidService: CovidService) {
  }

 
  ngOnInit(): void {
       this.getData();
  }  

  getData(){
    this.covidService.getData().subscribe(data=> {this.observations = data;});
    }
  

}
```

3. my html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h1>testing if it shows with bundle</h1>
        <p>{{observations}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

4. data interface

```
export interface Observation {
    entry: Entry[];
  }
  
export interface Entry {
    fullUrl: string;
    resource: Resource;
    search: Search;
  }
  
export interface Search {
    mode: string;
  }
  
export interface Resource {
    resourceType: string;
    id: string;
    meta: Meta2;
    status: string;
    category: Category[];
    code: Code;
    subject: Subject;
    encounter: Subject;
    effectiveDateTime: string;
    issued: string;
    valueCodeableConcept: Code;
  }
  
export interface Subject {
    reference: string;
  }
  
export interface Code {
    coding: Coding[];
    text: string;
  }
  
export interface Category {
    coding: Coding[];
  }
  
export interface Coding {
    system: string;
    code: string;
    display: string;
  }
  
export interface Meta2 {
    versionId: string;
    lastUpdated: string;
    source: string;
    profile: string[];
    tag: Tag[];
  }
  
export interface Tag {
    system: string;
    code: string;
  }
  
export interface Link {
    relation: string;
    url: string;
  }
  
export interface Meta {
    lastUpdated: string;
  }
```

5. nested json

```
{
    "resourceType": "Bundle",
    "id": "e64c9372-aa3c-4e58-8d9a-af0ef210707a",
    "meta": {
        "lastUpdated": "2020-10-01T15:31:00.321+00:00"
    },
    "type": "searchset",
    "total": 157,
    "link": [
        {
            "relation": "self",
            "url": "http://hapi.fhir.org/baseR4/Observation?code=94531-1"
        },
        {
            "relation": "next",
            "url": "http://hapi.fhir.org/baseR4?_getpages=e64c9372-aa3c-4e58-8d9a-af0ef210707a&_getpagesoffset=20&_count=20&_pretty=true&_bundletype=searchset"
        }
    ],
    "entry": [
        {
            "fullUrl": "http://hapi.fhir.org/baseR4/Observation/c6100c54-94b6-4ed8-8400-6e990c679ed4",
            "resource": {
                "resourceType": "Observation",
                "id": "c6100c54-94b6-4ed8-8400-6e990c679ed4",
                "meta": {
                    "versionId": "1",
                    "lastUpdated": "2020-03-24T17:53:09.595+00:00",
                    "source": "#wP11dHjLGlZ6MwzU",
                    "profile": [
                        "http://hl7.org/fhir/us/core/StructureDefinition/us-core-observation-lab"
                    ],
                    "tag": [
                        {
                            "system": "https://smarthealthit.org/tags",
                            "code": "Covid19 synthetic population from Synthea"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "status": "final",
                "category": [
                    {
                        "coding": [
                            {
                                "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/observation-category",
                                "code": "laboratory",
                                "display": "laboratory"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "code": {
                    "coding": [
                        {
                            "system": "http://loinc.org",
                            "code": "94531-1",
                            "display": "SARS-CoV-2 RNA Pnl Resp NAA+probe"
                        }
                    ],
                    "text": "SARS-CoV-2 RNA Pnl Resp NAA+probe"
                },
                "subject": {
                    "reference": "Patient/1b0580b9-1ee3-4353-b555-64c797d57564"
                },
                "encounter": {
                    "reference": "Encounter/135aee2a-f9d4-4627-ba9d-659ba067171d"
                },
                "effectiveDateTime": "2020-03-19T00:33:14-05:00",
                "issued": "2020-03-19T00:33:14.678-05:00",
                "valueCodeableConcept": {
                    "coding": [
                        {
                            "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",
                            "code": "10828004",
                            "display": "Positive (qualifier value)"
                        }
                    ],
                    "text": "Positive (qualifier value)"
                }
            },
            "search": {
                "mode": "match"
            }
        },
        {
            "fullUrl": "http://hapi.fhir.org/baseR4/Observation/41149276-9f25-4613-989a-0a58e3c95d92",
            "resource": {
                "resourceType": "Observation",
                "id": "41149276-9f25-4613-989a-0a58e3c95d92",
                "meta": {
                    "versionId": "1",
                    "lastUpdated": "2020-03-24T18:00:19.621+00:00",
                    "source": "#wjBsr5FxmhpDPleG",
                    "profile": [
                        "http://hl7.org/fhir/us/core/StructureDefinition/us-core-observation-lab"
                    ],
                    "tag": [
                        {
                            "system": "https://smarthealthit.org/tags",
                            "code": "Covid19 synthetic population from Synthea"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "status": "final",
                "category": [
                    {
                        "coding": [
                            {
                                "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/observation-category",
                                "code": "laboratory",
                                "display": "laboratory"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "code": {
                    "coding": [
                        {
                            "system": "http://loinc.org",
                            "code": "94531-1",
                            "display": "SARS-CoV-2 RNA Pnl Resp NAA+probe"
                        }
                    ],
                    "text": "SARS-CoV-2 RNA Pnl Resp NAA+probe"
                },
                "subject": {
                    "reference": "Patient/0c4a1143-8d1c-42ed-b509-eac97d77c9b2"
                },
                "encounter": {
                    "reference": "Encounter/18f34edf-875f-4c77-ad6d-5062a516f4c1"
                },
                "effectiveDateTime": "2020-01-14T11:52:35-06:00",
                "issued": "2020-01-14T11:52:35.648-06:00",
                "valueCodeableConcept": {
                    "coding": [
                        {
                            "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",
                            "code": "10828004",
                            "display": "Positive (qualifier value)"
                        }
                    ],
                    "text": "Positive (qualifier value)"
                }
            },
            "search": {
                "mode": "match"
            }
        },
        {
            "fullUrl": "http://hapi.fhir.org/baseR4/Observation/ae8d76ec-249e-45ac-a9fd-0e632ea492c9",
            "resource": {
                "resourceType": "Observation",
                "id": "ae8d76ec-249e-45ac-a9fd-0e632ea492c9",
                "meta": {
                    "versionId": "1",
                    "lastUpdated": "2020-03-24T18:05:48.309+00:00",
                    "source": "#XWpckBrCJJ9e7CXB",
                    "profile": [
                        "http://hl7.org/fhir/us/core/StructureDefinition/us-core-observation-lab"
                    ],
                    "tag": [
                        {
                            "system": "https://smarthealthit.org/tags",
                            "code": "Covid19 synthetic population from Synthea"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "status": "final",
                "category": [
                    {
                        "coding": [
                            {
                                "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/observation-category",
                                "code": "laboratory",
                                "display": "laboratory"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "code": {
                    "coding": [
                        {
                            "system": "http://loinc.org",
                            "code": "94531-1",
                            "display": "SARS-CoV-2 RNA Pnl Resp NAA+probe"
                        }
                    ],
                    "text": "SARS-CoV-2 RNA Pnl Resp NAA+probe"
                },
                "subject": {
                    "reference": "Patient/40c6abbe-96bb-4202-bed3-ddb9d8f68cb9"
                },
                "encounter": {
                    "reference": "Encounter/fa321fea-4d1d-485e-8c8b-4341255465b0"
                },
                "effectiveDateTime": "2020-01-11T21:00:42-06:00",
                "issued": "2020-01-11T21:00:42.718-06:00",
                "valueCodeableConcept": {
                    "coding": [
                        {
                            "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",
                            "code": "10828004",
                            "display": "Positive (qualifier value)"
                        }
                    ],
                    "text": "Positive (qualifier value)"
                }
            },
            "search": {
                "mode": "match"
            }
        },
        {
            "fullUrl": "http://hapi.fhir.org/baseR4/Observation/2d71d059-984b-4b13-b8b7-e9de2ee94f27",
            "resource": {
                "resourceType": "Observation",
                "id": "2d71d059-984b-4b13-b8b7-e9de2ee94f27",
                "meta": {
                    "versionId": "1",
                    "lastUpdated": "2020-03-24T18:08:38.202+00:00",
                    "source": "#zJ6AANWUU0Zx9Zjs",
                    "profile": [
                        "http://hl7.org/fhir/us/core/StructureDefinition/us-core-observation-lab"
                    ],
                    "tag": [
                        {
                            "system": "https://smarthealthit.org/tags",
                            "code": "Covid19 synthetic population from Synthea"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "status": "final",
                "category": [
                    {
                        "coding": [
                            {
                                "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/observation-category",
                                "code": "laboratory",
                                "display": "laboratory"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "code": {
                    "coding": [
                        {
                            "system": "http://loinc.org",
                            "code": "94531-1",
                            "display": "SARS-CoV-2 RNA Pnl Resp NAA+probe"
                        }
                    ],
                    "text": "SARS-CoV-2 RNA Pnl Resp NAA+probe"
                },
                "subject": {
                    "reference": "Patient/e5c6bf5f-772f-4fee-8d72-4d05bca3027d"
                },
                "encounter": {
                    "reference": "Encounter/eb0a6461-9103-409e-8773-0d13b827d32f"
                },
                "effectiveDateTime": "2020-03-11T10:56:41-05:00",
                "issued": "2020-03-11T10:56:41.928-05:00",
                "valueCodeableConcept": {
                    "coding": [
                        {
                            "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",
                            "code": "10828004",
                            "display": "Positive (qualifier value)"
                        }
                    ],
                    "text": "Positive (qualifier value)"
                }
            },
            "search": {
                "mode": "match"
            }
        },
```

Comment: try `<p>{{observations |  json}}</p>` it should help you view what's inside your object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The API returns an `Observation` which contains a list of `Entry` items, not a list of `Observation` items
2. Use `map` to transform from the `Observation` to the list of `Entry` items

```
export class CovidStatusComponent implements OnInit { 
   entries: Entry[];
   displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'entry','meta','status','subject'];
  
  constructor(private covidService: CovidService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
       this.getData();
  }  

  getData(){
    this.covidService.getData().subscribe(data=> {this.entries = data.map(d => d.entry);});
    }
}
```

Also:

`{{observation.entry.resource}}` won't work as `entry` is an array.
Use `{{observation.entry[0].resource}}` instead.

Answer (score 2):

With Angular Interpolation (the {{ observations}} syntax) you can only display strings.

### Extended Solution

In order to make this work you have to supply a property of the object. For example like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h1>testing if it shows with bundle</h1>
        <p>{{observations.id}}</p>
        <p>{{observations.meta}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

But these:

1. `<p>{{observations.entry}}</p>`
2. `<p>{{observations.entry.fullUrl}}</p>`

will both not work because "entry" is an array with many objects. So you could do something like this:

`<p>{{observations.entry[0].fullUrl}}</p>`

and it would definitely work. It takes the first object from the "entry" array. If you want to display all entries you have to iterate over it. Try this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h1>testing if it shows with bundle</h1>
        <p>{{observations.id}}</p>
        <p *ngFor="let e of observations.entry">{{ e.fullUrl }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This will display the value of "fullUrl" for every object in the entry array. If you have multiple "observations" as your variable name lets assume you have to iterate over them too like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h1>testing if it shows with bundle</h1>
        <div *ngFor="let observation of observations">
            <p>{{observations.id}}</p>
            <p *ngFor="let e of observation.entry">{{ e.fullUrl }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### Quick solution

If you want a quick and dirty solution to just have a look at the result you can use the "json" pipe:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h1>testing if it shows with bundle</h1>
        <p>{{ observations | json }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

your data is an array
observations: Observation[];
so if you want to display all of data use *ngFor

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>FullUrl </th>
    <th>Search Mode</th>
    <th>resource Id</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of observation.entry">
    <td>{{ item.fullUrl }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.search.mode}}</td>
    <td>{{item.resource.id </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

and if sub is also array  you can use sub loop *ngFor like
item.resource.category

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>FullUrl </th>
    <th>Search Mode</th>
    <th>resource Id</th>
    <th> resource category</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of observation.entry">
    <td>{{ item.fullUrl }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.search.mode}}</td>
    <td>{{item.resource.id </td> 
<td>
<span *ngFor="let cat of item.resource.category">
{{cat.coding.display}}
      </span> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

make sure if data is array you can use *ngFor or index of array item.resource.category[0]
then . field ...